# How to use preg_match() to extract specific data using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

**Problem:**

Only extract the first < ul class="list">< /ul> from a webpage using preg_match and dump it into an array.

**Code:**

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com');
preg_match('#<ul class="list">(.*)</ul>#i', $str, $matches);
```

**Desired goal:**

To get the first < ul> and dump it all in an array. < ul> should be parent and every element inside should be child.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` is a string manipulation function, and knows nothing of "child elements", so will never be able to return the array you are hoping for.

You need to use a library capable of parsing the HTML for you, such as [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or the built-in DOM library's [loadHTML method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

[**Edit** - The "never" above is a slight exaggeration: you could, with a bit of effort, write your own mini-parser using nothing but `preg_match`, but it would be inflexible and unmaintainable compared to using an HTML parsing library.]

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com');
preg_match('~<ul class="list">(.*?)</ul>~si', $str, $matches);
```

Use .*? to match first and closest closing tag. If you use .* it will find first  on the page. I assume your UL tag is correct.

You also need **si** *flags* as in **s = single-line** and **i = insensitive**.
Otherwise your pattern breaks on first \n.

**PS**: *If your UL contains UL children, you should consider parsing using the **DOMDocument** and an **DOMXPath** query. It's safer for more complex HTML.*

*Hope it helps.*

Answer (score 0):

you want to use .+? or you may grab more than just the first ul if there are several.

```
preg_match( '/<ul class="list">(.+?)<\/ul>/mis', $str, $match );

preg_match_all( '/<li>(.+?)<\/li>/mis', $match[1], $lis );

$answer = array ( 'ul' => $lis[1] );
```

I think that is what you were looking for